# Failed to parse the expression [#{myGalleryBean.photos.stream.filter((i)->i.selected eq true).toList()}]

Tags: jsf, lambda, el, java-ee-6

I am trying to do a for loop over a list and show the images that are selected only.

I am using this code in my index.xhtml:

[image: My code]

But I keep getting the following error:

> /index.xhtml @87,73 value="#{myGalleryBean.photos.stream.filter((i)->i.selected eq true).toList()}" Failed to parse the expression [#{myGalleryBean.photos.stream.filter((i)->i.selected eq true).toList()}]

I have this code working on Java EE 7, but after changing to Java EE 6 I got that error.

Any help on how to do this in Java EE 6 would be really appreciated.

Comment: Streaming was introduced in JDK7

Comment: @kolossus; No, in Java 8. But this is unrelated.

Comment: David, posting code as image instead of code is considered rude (not copypasteable, not searchable, etc). In future questions, post code as code.